# Is it possible to automatically transform a Dropship Purchase Order into an Item Fulfillment using a Workflow?

Tags: netsuite, fulfillment

I would like to schedule a workflow to find all items that belong to a purchase order that has been marked as shipped by the vendor and mark them as shipped. Doing this manually, Netsuite takes you to the Item Fulfillment form. When I attempt to establish a workflow to transform the purchase order record, I am unable to find 'Item Fulfillment' in the "Record Type" drop-down when establishing the Workflow action. My options are "Item Receipt," "Vendor Bill," and "Vendor Return Authorization." Any workarounds if this isn't possible to do this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and transform the Sales Order instead.
The button you are clicking is just redirecting you to the Sales Order.